# Autoincrement textbox value when new sheet is created

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make my textbox values more flexible. So when I create new sheets their values are incremented on the specified number.

Based on [this solution](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/reference-cell.896507/) I used the following code:

```
Sub CivBoxNext()
    With ActiveSheet
        Range("D51").Select
        .Shapes("Civils 3").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ActiveCell.Value + 2
        Range("D52").Select
        .Shapes("Civils 4").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ActiveCell.Value + 2
    End With
End Sub
```

which next I plotted into the code creating the new sheet as a `Call` method:

```
Sub Civilssheet()

Dim I As Long
Dim xNumber As Integer
Dim xName As String
Dim xActiveSheet As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xActiveSheet = ActiveSheet
xNumber = InputBox("Enter number of times to copy the current sheet")
For I = 1 To xNumber
    xName = ActiveSheet.Name
    xActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Civils2")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Civils" & I + 2
Next
Call CivBoxNext
xActiveSheet.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True    

End Sub
```

It works, but only on the one following sheet.

Afterward, I have another 3 sheets, which numeration should change at the same moment.

[image]

I tried another option, like changing the target cell value when creating a new sheet and next feed my textbox from this cell.

I used the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim ws As Worksheet
j = 0
For Each ws In Worksheets

    I = ws.Range("D51").Value

    If I > j Then
        j = I
    End If

Next
ActiveSheet.Range("D51").Value = j + 2
End Sub
```

which comes from:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/auto-increase-a-cell-value-1-when-a-new-sheet-is-created.334786/

How can I do the cell value autoincrement when creating the new sheet?

Shall I fiddle with the traditional Excel formulas at once instead of VBA?

Comment: is it always just those sheets?

Comment: Hmm I would like to have as much flexible amount of sheets as possible. Effectively the guys will create mostly 1 sheet for civils and another 1 for cables. So in this event when they create 1 new ones in civils I want to have values incremented in all sheets onnwards down to the end. When they create the cable sheet it's easier, because this is the last sheet in this array, so I can do it manually as per as above.

Comment: Looks like you are having some issues with your tab creation loop as well. It only creates the last one.

Answer (score 1):

This will merge your subs. Can you see if it meets your needs?

```
Sub Civilssheet()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Civils9")
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xNumber, valCivics, valCivicsFin As Integer

    xNumber = InputBox("Enter number of times to copy the current sheet")

    On Error Resume Next

    ' extract highest Civics worksheet number
    For I = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        If InStr(1, Sheets(I).Name, "Civils") > 0 Then
            valCivics = Val(Replace(Sheets(I).Name, "Civils", ""))
            If valCivics > valCivicsFin Then valCivicsFin = valCivics
        End If
    Next

    For I = 1 To xNumber
        ' add worksheet to the end of existing worksheets
        ws.Copy After:=Sheets(Application.Sheets.Count)
        ' name the new worksheet with the highest value + 1
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Civils" & I + valCivicsFin
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Civils 3").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 4).Value + 2
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Civils 4").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(52, 4).Value + 2
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I can upvote, because the code works itself. Unfortunately, it's not what I want. The newly created sheets come at the very end of my document. I don't want that. I want this sheet to be placed right behind the "Civils 2". Autoincrementation works, but again I want it from this new "Civils3" sheet down to the next 3 "Cable" sheets.

Comment: I have already sorted the new sheet location. I put ws.Copy After:=Sheets("Civils" & I + 1). I also did the increment for the following sheets:
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Civils 4").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(52, 4).Value + I * 2
Teoreticallly I know how to deal with the next ones (cable), but I have no clue how to decrement these values when some sheet is removed.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote but lets get you sorted. Can you update your question with and `EDIT:` and add your new code?

Comment: Basically I have created the new one, which is here:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950199/vba-excel-autoincrement-value-on-the-following-sheet-when-changing-data-on-acti/60950751#60950751